# Не обновляются изменение на WP

Tags: wordpress

На сайте не обновляются изменения. К примеру, редактирую файл `custom.js`, в нем в самом низу для слайдера `slick` отключил авто переключение, перезаливаю редактируемый файл с помощью FTP.

При переходе на сайт и открытии файла `custom.js` не вижу изменений в файле, хотя при открытие этого же файла через FTP изменения есть. Так же очистка кеша не помогает. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Comment: Кеширование ибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего корень проблемы в кешировании на стороне сервера. Некоторые хостинг провайдеры включают его в целях оптимизации ресурсов.

В этом нет ничего страшного. Периодически кеш обновляется и со временем Вы сможете увидеть внесённые Вами изменения и в браузере.

Если же это сильно мешает в работе, можно обратиться в техническую поддержку хостинга чтобы для Вашего сайта кеширование отключили.

Также неисключено, что на самом сайте установлен специальный плагин, который осуществляет кеширование данных на сервере.

В этом случае, настроить, а также включить или отключить кеширование можете только Вы или пользователь с правами администратора.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно дело в хостинге!